# Hibernate GeneratedValue starting from 1 although there are some data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-mapping

I was developing a spring-hibernate app which worked well till I chose to migrate to SQL Server to import some data easily

The problem is after importing (the ID column was filled by numbers till 18,000),
when I try to add another row to my database, hibernate generates ID beginning from 1 (I used Auto, Table, Sequence, and Identity)

Is there a solution for this problem ?

Or should I import the data starting from a big value for ID column ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq", initialValue=18000, allocationSize=100)
public class EntityWithSequenceId {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq")
    @Id long id;

}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much you saved me.

Although I don't know what allocationSize mean ? and would it differ to be 100 or 50 ?